# Use of rownum in batching the data from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently i was using the rownum in the sql query to fetch the data from oracle db in batch of 1000 records. for example 1 to 1000, 1001 to 2000 etc.

Note:

1. I have about a million records in the table
2. I am querying the table to get records 1000 at a time

I used the below query

```
SELECT NAME FROM (
    SELECT NAME, ROWNUM RN 
      FROM employee
) WHERE RN  >= ? AND RN <= ?
```

to fetch the data but stuck in strange issue.
The records in the db are unique but after complete execution I end up getting some duplicate record.

Is there any issue with the query? Is rownum causing issue? Is it possible that the record fetched in first batch of 1000 is also coming in the next subsequent batch?

Comment: To your second question, the thought that popped into my mind immediately is whether someone else is inserting records as you go along.  In this case, then yes, you could certainly see duplicates coming back.  They wouldn't really be "duplicates," but they could be records you saw in an earlier tab.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  well if the range are `(1,1000)` and `(1001,2000)` the query should work fine

Answer (score 2):

You can't trust the order of records returned from a query without an explicit `order by` clause. If the inner query doesn't return values in the same order in each execution, you may get the same row in two separate executions, and thus duplicates in the overall execution.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any issue with the query? Is rownum causing issue?

Yes, Oracle does not guarantee you that a common ordering will be used each time you see the output from a query. So `ROWNUM`, without an `ORDER BY` is not useful.Try these options.

In 11g use `row_number` with an `order by`, in Oracle 12c use `FETCH..FIRST` syntax, you should have a primary key / unique key column for this to work.

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM   (SELECT NAME, 
               row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   ORDER BY primary_key_col ) rn 
        FROM   employee) 
WHERE  rn >=? 
       AND rn <=? ;

SELECT   NAME 
FROM     employee 
ORDER BY primary_key_col offset ? FETCH first ? rows only;
```